# Xbox 360 console Installation

Tags: xbox-360

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will installing a game on Xbox allow me to bypass a location at which the disc becomes unreadable?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/43713/will-installing-a-game-on-xbox-allow-me-to-bypass-a-location-at-which-the-disc-b)

So I have a video game for my Xbox 360 console, I installed it so where it loads from the hard drive not the disc. I am wondering If that disc got scratched (the one I installed) would it still load everything perfect?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is, probably.

When you start a game that you've installed, the console still checks the disc to make sure that it matches the game that you're starting. As long as that check passes, it doesn't use anything from the disc for the rest of the time that you play it.